# How to access an Obj-C public instance variable in RubyMotion without a getter?

Tags: objective-c, macos, rubymotion

I am using a 3rd party Obj-C static library for and API in a RubyMotion project and one of the classes in the library defines some public instance variables in the interface section in the API header file. Here is the code as it's pretty short:

```
@interface TransporterFile : NSObject
{
@public
    NSString *name;
    TransporterFileType type;
    NSDate *modifyTime;
    NSDate *createTime;
    unsigned long long size;
}
- (BOOL) isFolder;
- (BOOL) isShared;
@end
```

In ObjC, these values can be reached like this:
    name = transporterFile->name
but there is no getter defined so you can't use dot notation.

In RubyMotion, probably because there is no getter, there is no instance variable exposed to me. I have tried using the .instance_variables method and it returns an empty array. I also tried the instance_variable_get('@name') method but that doesn't work either. I am able to call the two methods isFolder and isShared and they work as expected.

Update: I tried doing a similar thing in the Swift language and it had similar problems and that led me to a suggestion to use the valueForKeyPath('name') method to access the 'name' instance variable. That worked in Swift and led me to check if a similar method was available to RubyMotion. The good news is that this works but is a bit clunky so I'll leave this question open for now in the hope that a better answer is available.

I realise the 3rd party library is not following best practice and I will recommend to the vendor that they define some properties instead if using instance variables directly but for now I need a workaround.

Can anyone please suggest a way to access these public instance variables from RubyMotion or perhaps by wrapping the vendor's library in another ObjC library. I've never written an ObjC library (wrapper or not) so would appreciate some advice before I embark on this option.

The full API can be seen here: https://secure.connecteddata.com/developer
Note that I'm using Mac OS X 10.10 with Xcode 6.1.1 and the latest version of RubyMotion. The Mac OS X API download from the above site is missing the header file so I used the header from the iOS download.

Many thanks,
Craig.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my question to explain that I found the following method allows me to access the public instance variables.

```
obj.valueForKeyPath('name')
```

However, I'd be happy to hear of any better ways to do this as it's a bit clunky.

ps. Why is it that I can spend hours trying to find a solution to a problem then within minutes of posting the question on an open forum, I find a potential answer? Grr... :)